# How many tangents to the curve $y=x^3-px$ , can be drawn from different points in the plane?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, functions

$y=x^3-px$
so as ussual we find the slope of any tangent to the curve at a point $x_0$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=3x^2-p$

$3x_0^2-p$ 
so  the equation of the tangent is

$y=-x_0^3+px_0+(3x_0^2-p)(x-x_0)\\y=x(3x_0^2-p)-2x_0^3$

if we draw a tangent from $(x_1,y_1)$  where    $y_1\ne x_1^3-px_1  $
, our interest is how many such different pairs can we find that are tangent to the curve...
obxiously $x_0$ is unique in the sense that only one such point exist but our interest is what about other points on the graph....help will be appreciated

Comment: In this generality even by a CAS the problem is difficult ...

Comment: but suprisingly this was asked in a high school contest problem IMO ,[imo problem,39,1972][1]


  [1]: http://books.google.nl/books?id=okx0d9jdM8oC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=imo%20How%20many%20tangents%20to%20the%20curve%20y=x3%E2%88%92px%20,%20can%20be%20drawn%20from%20different%20points%20in%20the%20plane?&source=bl&ots=ZyiqI2FX_8&sig=lqs0tOxingp9QOvTKu_wLi8bI7k&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=pNOHUvHkMorIswag2YDgCg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=imo%20How%20many%20tangents%20to%20the%20curve%20y=x3%E2%88%92px%20,%20can%20be%20drawn%20from%20different%20points%20in%20the%20plane?&f=false